# How to calculate NDCG with binary relevances using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ranking

I'm trying to calculate the NDCG score for binary relevances:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
y_true = [0, 1, 0]
y_pred = [0, 1, 0]
ndcg_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

And getting:

```
ValueError: Only ('multilabel-indicator', 'continuous-multioutput',  
'multiclass-multioutput') formats are supported. Got binary instead
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try:

```
from sklearn.metrics import ndcg_score
y_true = [[0, 1, 0]]
y_pred = [[0, 1, 0]]
ndcg_score(y_true, y_pred)
1.0
```

Note the expected shapes in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ndcg_score.html):

> y_true: ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_labels)
> y_score: ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_labels)